# Do not understand form action right

Tags: forms, action

This is the first time I've try to use a formulae to make a contact page on my site.

This is the code I use (and tried to adapt for my purposes):

```
    <div id="main" class="content container bottom clearfix">
    <div class="cont row">  
    <!-- FORM-->
    <div class="form sevencol" style="width:52%">          
    <form action="mailto:contact@stefanseifert.com" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <ul class="contactform">
    <li><input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="" class="required requiredField"/>
    <label for="contactName">Name</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required requiredField email"/>
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>   
    </li>
    <li class="textarea">
    <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" rows="10" cols="10" class=" required requiredField"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lf-ueMSAAAAAExUbwjvdqnNuNjlkeN3_wQyl720"></script>
    <noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lf-ueMSAAAAAExUbwjvdqnNuNjlkeN3_wQyl720" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript>                        
    </li>
    <li class="buttons"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true"/>
    <button type="submit" class="submit superlink">E-Mail senden</button>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    </div>
    <!-- END FORM-->           
    </div>
```

The result of it, is that every time I test it my Email program opens and fills part of the code inside a new mail of mine.
What is wrong here?

What I wanted was that a mail with the content of the input fields is sent to me, instead!
Appreciate your help!
Thanks very much

Garavani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send an email out of the browser.

`<form action="mailto:contact@stefanseifert.com" ...` specifies what should happen, once the form is submitted. This action opens the standard email client to send an email to that address - that's what you experienced.

if you want the email to be sent automatically by a server to you, you need to implement it in php, c#, java - or any other language on that server, and send the form data to the server

Comment: I don’t know why stackoverflow does not want me to say thank you, but thank you nevertheless! (even if I may now be banned from this place). Is it difficult to explain to me how to do this in php?